# changing the position of an object in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array with objects. And all i want to do is to move this object to the next position of the array and delete it from the previous position.my objects are humans and they have only one attribute(sex(if they are male or female)).But really i don't know how can i do this.Any suggestions?my code is this:

```
    Humans[][] array = new Humans[7][7];

    public int sex() {
        return sex;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            for (Humans[] inner : array) {
                for (Humans h : inner) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to move the *reference* to the object to the next position, and delete (ie, NULL) the *reference* from where it was?  What happens to whatever was previously in the place you'll be moving the reference to?

Comment: yes i mean this.for now i have only one object and i don't care about anything else

Comment: Why are you using arrays and not a fitting collection?

Comment: i am very new in java and i don't know a lot about this language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is move the object from entry [N] to entry [N+1] in a 1-dimensional array, it doesn't require a loop:

```
void moveEntry(Humans[] array, int index) {
    array[index + 1] = array[index];
    array[index] = null;
}
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do with the 2-dimensional array, though.

### An attempt to understand what you want

```
void moveRight(Humans[][] array, int x, int y) {
    array[y][x + 1] = array[y][x];
    array[y][x] = null;
}
void moveUp(Humans[][] array, int x, int y) {
    array[y + 1][x] = array[y][x];
    array[y][x] = null;
}
```

Comment: Hallo and thank you for your help.Imagine that there is a place divide in blocks and also that there is a human who can go from one block to another.I want to do this because i will add the chance the human to go to an upper (for example block).Thanks anyway

Comment: So you want to move one of two directions, depending?  I'll update things.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the old `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
```

This way you can use `i+1` to refer to the next position in the array. You can then copy the item from the `i`th position to the `(i+1)`th position and set the `i`th position to `null`.

Comment: Well, can you show us the code in which you tried doing it this way?